# Как добиться появление ошибки "Недостаточно памяти" в программе при выделении памяти?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <malloc.h>

using namespace std;

class Students {
    long double s;
public:
    void * operator new(size_t size, char* str = "New");
    void operator delete(void* ptr); 

    void * operator new[](size_t fullsize, char* str = "New []");
    void operator delete[](void* ptr);
};

#include "Student.h"

void * Students::operator new(size_t size, char* str) 
{

cout << "\n" << str << "\n";

void*ptr = malloc(size);

if (!ptr)
{
    cout << "\nError memory new\n";
} else {

    cout << "\nMemory new - OK\n";
}

return ptr;
}

void * Students::operator new[](size_t fullsize, char* str)
{

    cout << "\n" << str << "\n";

    void*ptr = malloc(fullsize);
    if (!ptr) {

        cout << "\nError memory new[]\n";

    }
    else {
        cout << "\nMemory new - OK\n";
    }

    return ptr;

}

void Students::operator delete(void* ptr)
{

    free(ptr);
    cout << "\nDelete memory\n";

}



void Students::operator delete[](void* ptr) 
{

    free(ptr);
    cout << "\nDelete [] memory\n";

}


#include <iostream> 
#include "Student.h"


using namespace std; 

int main() {



    Students* student = new Students;
    Students* a = new Students;

    delete a;
    delete[] student;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну в бесконечном цикле создавайте ваших студентов, авось через миллиард память и исчерпается... Хотите меньше - добавьте прямо в класс поле типа `char dummy[1000000];` :)

Comment: `throw L"Недостаточно памяти";`

Comment: ОС общего назначения выгружает слишком большую кучу в своп-файл. А чтобы переполнить своп-файл при нынешних размерах дисков надо запросить действительно МНОГО памяти. :-) И да, работать надо в 64-битной системе. По нынешним временам для 32-битных систем счастливого события исчерпания кучи может и не наступить. Или наоборот, можно попробовать работать под DOS. Там куча маленькая и свопа нет. Правда и диагностика исчерпания кучи криво сделана.

Comment: Я так понимаю, это нужно для тестирования: нормально ли отлавливается такая ошибка в вашей программе. На время тестирования следует отключить своп-файл. И не удивляться, когда начнут вылетать с этой ошибкой другие приложения...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать нечто [такое](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XUNbb1xklsDvaLIe):

```
int main()
{
    auto size = -1ull;
    new int[size];
}
```

Результат:

> ```
> terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_alloc: std::bad_alloc
> ```

Т.е. `new` не смог выделить память и выкинул исключение `std::bad_alloc`, как того требует стандарт языка С++. Мы это исключение никак не ловили, поэтому вызвался `std::terminate`, который и привёл к завершению программы. 
По сути это и есть ошибка "Недостаточно памяти". Можно довесить обработчик и вывести уже свою строку, если хочется, но сути дела это не меняет.

Любопытно заметить, что если убрать переменную `size` (или сделать её `const`), то [ошибку получим](https://wandbox.org/permlink/TiZ6CNshZyieoQ9Y) ещё на стадии компиляции:

```
new int[-1ull];
```

> ```
> error: array is too large (18446744073709551615 elements)
> ```